# Unlocking an O2 Iphone

Tags: iphone, unlock

I was asked if I could unlock an iPhone today, the answer was, of course, a resounding no. Intrigued, I dug a little deeper to see what would be required and if it were possible.

All of the information I found either led to using the o2(UK) form or using a third party site. He tells me that after a long arduous conversation with 02 that the firm option is not viable for him. So I'm wondering, what is it that these various sites offer to do that is different from this 'form'. All they ask for is the IMEI number, cash and in return a promise that it'll be unlocked in x number of days.

As far as I'm aware Apple has a particular contract with the network meaning that some sort of communication needs to pass back and forth between them to enable this unlocking to take place else it may well be temporary.

So, with that in mind, are these sites suggesting that they get in touch with both Apple & the network, is it their contacts within the relevant depts that we're effectively paying for.

Is there another solution?
I wouldn't mind attempting to unlock an old phone I have just for the 'tadaaa' factor, we do love it when we get things to work that perhaps we shouldn't have. :D

Thanks in advance for any advice, answers, suggestions or tips.

also, if there's a programmatic way of solving this...I'm all ears, I'll happily tear my phone apart and rig it up to a circuit if it means solving the mystery.

Comment: Why is O2 not viable - I thought by law they had to allow switching

Comment: @mark, no idea. He simply said that they said no and that was that. I didn't bother going into the details.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried one of those sites in 2010 to unlock my iPhone 4 (SFR), it worked perfectly and I'm still using it. I think that these types of websites have people with access to Apple databases and can easily unlock it from there. I can't think of another way to unlock your phone without going through the original carrier, Apple or these websites. You can still change the mother board but that's like changing the phone.

There are jailbreak methods you may want to check [iClarified](http://www.iclarified.com/unlock) they'll tell how and if you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link. [Macworld](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iphone/how-unlock-your-iphone-use-any-sim-ee-o2-vodafone-three-3501427/) and you will find it's easy, legal, and not a jail break. So long as the phone is yours, you can unlock it. I don't think they can actually refuse (The carriers that is) - although the young chap on the desk may not know about it...

Comment: And note for o2 it disagrees with the OP " if you're not an O2 customer, you can simply put a non-O2 SIM card into the iPhone, plug it in to your computer and then open iTunes to unlock the iPhone,"